# Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

Tags: apt

While trying to update I am getting these errors.

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-calc_5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-base-core_5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libr/libreoffice/libreoffice-core_5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mesa/libxatracker2_17.2.8-0ubuntu0~17.10.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/simple-scan/simple-scan_3.26.3-0ubuntu0.17.10.0_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird_52.6.0+build1-0ubuntu0.17.10.1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: "Unable to connect" indicates a network problem, perhaps not an Ubuntu problem. Does your network work? Are you behind a proxy? How long has this problem been occurring (or was it one-time)?

Comment: First try to verify that you are able to connect to the internet at all (`ping google.com`). Then try if you can reach the server (`ping in.archive.ubuntu.com`). Then try if you are able to connect to port 80 (`nc in.archive.ubuntu.com 80`)
The solution would depend on where it fails for you.

Comment: This isn't just a network issue. I had this same problem while trying to create a chroot of lxde on a chromebook with crouton. It gives me a bunch of this right at the very end of the process, following a very long string of completely successful downloads of other stuff needed for the process, mostly from the ubuntu package servers, same as these that failed seemed to be trying to download from.